# Application Gateway, with Isolated Application Service Environment and Web app

Tags: azure

I am setting  up an Application Gateway in front of an Isolated App Environment. I have set up a domain name for the app environment eg mywebapp.com. I then Created a self signed certificate for the ILB of the app service environment and uploaded it to the Application Service environment. Next I created a web app and placed it in the above app service environment, the app name is app01.mywebapp.com. I added a custom domain name in the web app called awebapp.mydomain.com and validated this. I then pointed the custom domain name awebapp.mydomain.com to the DNS of the Application Gateway so all traffic for this domain name goes via the app gateway.

In application gateway I create a listener for the above hostname (awebapp.mydomain.com) using front end IP configuration and Frontend Port 80

Whilst configuring the APP Gateway Backend Pool...do you enter in App service Load Balancer IP or the hostname of the app service environment domain webapp.com or even the web app host name app01.mywebapp.com?

Then the probes - what hostname goes here? the custom domain name given to the web app in the web app settings eg awebapp.mydomain.com, the app service domain name  mywebapp.com , the webapp domain name app01.mywebapp.com or the custom domain name awebapp.mydomain.com?????

Its all very confusing - no documentation I have seen actually explains the above..

Comment: Not really as i followed every instruction and it says unknown error. I exactly followed this document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/integrate-with-application-gateway.Also why is there such an awful unhelpful error message...Unknown Error please try again later?  That makes no sense whatsoever, if the app gateway doesnt know then how can you troubleshoot it ? I can hit the web app fine from a vm using the FQDN , the web app is up, I followed these instructions  nobody seems to provide an answer it seems no one really knows...thats why its unknown.

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt really matter. probe has has to reach the website and get 200-399 back. you dont even have to use hostname when creating probe. so either way works. for the backend pool it makes more sense to use load balanced endpoint.

Overall your question has very little to do with application gateway